# polling a file directory every tuesday moning at 8:00 using apache camel

Tags: apache-camel

I am busy with an apache camel project that automates the process of uploading a file to a SFTP server every tuesday at 8:00.

I want to set the delay of my apache camel route to: every tuesday at 8:00.

How would i go about doing that?

Let's say 'A' is my pickup location and 'B' is my destination location.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Quartz](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html) component as scheduler, [pollEnrich](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) for reading the file, and the [FTP](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html) component for sending its content:

```
from("quartz://myscheduler?cron=0+0+8+?+*+THU")
    .pollEnrich("file:inbox?fileName=data.txt")
    .to("ftp://foo@127.0.0.1:21/?password=pwd")
```

More information about the cron expression can be found [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/crontrigger).

Answer (score 3):

If you use Apache Camel 2.12 or better then the file consumer (and any other consumer which is scheduler based) has options to use a cron scheduler out of the box, either from spring or quartz2.

I wrote a blog entry about this summarizing about this

- http://www.davsclaus.com/2013/08/apache-camel-212-even-easier-cron.html

Its the scheduler option

- http://camel.apache.org/file2

And there is some examples at this page, see section *QuartzScheduledPollConsumerScheduler*

- http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html

Answer (score 0):

You can generally use the `camel-quartz` component like this:

```
from("quartz://myscheduler?cron=0+0+8+*+*+2")
    // do stuff
```

But on second look, I'm not sure how this would work as an sftp Consumer (can you do `from("quartz...").from("sftp...")` in camel? I'm not so sure.

On [this thread](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Scheduled-SFTP-consumer-td5741976.html) there is information about how to implement this via a `RoutePolicy`.

Good luck.